# Error clicking button in form with Jaunt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jaunt-api

So I am trying to submit a form using Jaunt. There are two submit buttons, a check and apply. I am Trying to click the check button but am having some trouble because it cant find the button with the identifier of "check".

I am basically copying what is done on the Jaunt tutorial #15,
http://jaunt-api.com/jaunt-tutorial.htm
I have tried the value of the button as well but to no luck

Code:

```
form.submit("Check");
```

Html:

```
<input name="action" class="a-button-input" type="submit" value="checkValue" aria-labelledby="gc-redemption-check-value-announce">

<span id="gc-redemption-check-value-announce" class="a-button-text" aria-hidden="true">
    <span id="gc-redemption-check-value-button-text" class="a-size-base">Check</span>
  </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Jaunt thing is not work maybe you can try jQuery

```
$('.submitButton').click(function(){
  $('form').submit();
});
```